# Как исправить неинициализрованный char

Tags: c++, c, char

В общем надо как то инициализировать char для вызова в функции, но не понимаю как, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Общий код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#define N 3
class stars {
    char *name;
    double massa;
    double part;
    double count;
        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &stream, stars &o1);
    friend istream & operator>>(istream &stream, stars &o1);
    friend void shapka(void);
    friend void linebuild(void);
    friend int isvalid(int a, int b);
public:

    stars() { massa = 0; count = 0; }
    stars(const char *a, double b, double c, double d);
    void setall( char *a, double &b, double &c , double &d);
    void getall(const char *a, double& b, double &c, double &d);
    void showall(void);
    stars& operator = (const stars &o1);
    int   operator == (stars &o1);
    stars operator + (stars &o1);

};
void linebuild(void) {
    cout << "\n|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
}
void shapka(void)
{
    cout << "_______________________________________________________________\n";
    cout << "|         Буддистские монастыри Японии периода Нара           |\n";
    cout << "|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
    cout << "|  Название  | Школа | Количество монахов | Площадь земли(га) |\n";
    cout << "|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream &stream, stars &o1) {
    shapka();
    stream << "|" << setw(10) << o1.name << "  |  ";
    stream << setw(5) << o1.massa << "|";
    stream << setw(18) << o1.part << "  |";
    stream << setw(17) << o1.count << "  |" << endl;
    linebuild();
    return stream;
}
istream & operator>>(istream &stream, stars &o1) {
    cout << "Название, Школа, Количество монахов, Площадь земли: \n";
    stream >> o1.name;
    stream >> o1.massa;
    stream >> o1.part;
    stream >> o1.count;
    return stream;
}
stars::stars(const char *a, double b, double c, double d) {
    name = new char[strlen(a) + 1];
    strcpy(name, a);
    massa = b;
    part = c;
    count = d;
}
int isvalid(int a, int b) {
    if (((a > N - 1) || (a < 0)) || ((b > N - 1) || (b < 0)))
    {
        cout << "Ошибка! Экземпляра с таким индексом не существует.\n";
        _getch();
        return -1;
    }
    else if (a == b)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка! Экземпляр не может быть записан сам в себя.\n";
        _getch();
        return -2;
    }
    return 0;
}

stars stars::operator + ( stars &o1) {
    stars tr;
    int i, j;
    delete[] tr.name;
    tr.name = new char[strlen(name) + strlen(o1.name) + 2];
    strcpy(tr.name, name);
    strcat(tr.name, o1.name);
    tr.massa = massa + o1.massa;
    tr.part = part + o1.part;
    tr.count = count + o1.count;
    return tr;
}

int stars::operator == (stars &o1) {
    if (count != o1.count) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; _getch(); }
    else if (ceil(massa) != ceil(o1.massa)) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; _getch(); }
    else if (ceil(part) != ceil(o1.part)) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; _getch(); }
    else if (strcmp(name, o1.name) != 0) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; _getch(); }
    else cout << "Экземпляры класса равны."; _getch();
    return 0;
}

stars& stars::operator = (const stars &o1) {
    delete[] name;
    name = new char[strlen(o1.name) + 2];
    if (!name) {
        cout << "Ошибка! Память не выделена.";
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(name, o1.name);
    massa = o1.massa;
    part = o1.part;
    count = o1.count;
    return *this;
}
void stars::showall(void) {
    cout << name << " ";
    cout << massa << " ";
    cout << part << " ";
    cout << count << " ";
}
void stars::setall(char *a, double &b, double &c, double &d) {
    strcpy(name, a);
    massa = b;
    part = c;
    count = d;
}
void stars::getall(const char * a, double &b,double &c, double &d)
{
    delete[] a;
    a = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    b = massa;
    c = part;
    d = count;
    cout << a << " ";
    cout << b << " ";
    cout << c << " ";
    cout << d << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
void system(){

}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    const char *n;
    double t;
    double s;
    double h;
    short i, k;
    unsigned int s1;
    short q, q1;
    stars obj[N] = { stars("Т",22,38.8,32.4),
              stars("С",50,54.7,34),
               stars("Д",10,12.2,55) };
    system("cls");
    cout.precision(3);
    cout << "Название, Школа, Количество монахов, Площадь земли: \n";
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        obj[i].showall();
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\nПерегрузка оператора присваивания '='.\n";
    cout << "Введите номера экземпляров класса: заменяемый и заменяющий>\n";
    cin >> q;
    cin >> q1;
    if (isvalid(q, q1) != 0) exit(-1);
    obj[q] = obj[q1];

    cout << "Название, Школа, Количество монахов, Площадь земли: \n";
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        obj[i].showall();
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\nПерегрузка оператора суммы '+'.\n";
    cout << "Введите номера экземпляров класса, которые надо сложить>\n";
    cin >> q;
    cin >> q1;
    stars temp;
    if (isvalid(q, q1) != 0) exit(-1);
    temp = obj[q]+obj[q1];
    cout << "Наименование, Тип, Посевная площадь, Урожайность: ";

    temp.getall(n,s,t,h);
}
```

Проблема в данном этапе:

```
temp.getall(n,s,t,h);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void stars::getall(const char * a, double &b,double &c, double &d)
{
    delete[] a;
    ...
}
```

удалять объекты без проверки их существования не очень хорошо

```
void stars::getall(const char * a, double &b,double &c, double &d)
{
    if (a != nullptr)
        delete[] a;
    ...
}
```

у вас в функции `main`

```
const char *n;
```

и потом она используется только при вызове

```
temp.getall(n,s,t,h);
```

а внутри `getall` произойдет удаление **неинициализированной** переменной!!!

Сделайте так:

```
char *n = nullptr;
```

и вообще зачем вы `n` константным то объявили?

Comment: Удаление нулевого указателя ничего не делает, так что `if` не нужен.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну ок, я ретроград :))) Но в приведенном коде `n` не инициализирован, поэтому, как мне кажется, и все беды